# How to prevent line break while splitting paragraph across two pages?

Tags: formatting

I have some long paragraphs which I want to be able to split over two pages. However I do not like the split mid-sentence.
So yes to paragraph split but no to sentence split. Is this possible?

For small paragraph splits I use the nowidow package. But this does break the sentence if it is not split.

Example code:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[defaultlines=3,all]{nowidow} %No paragraph breaks, exept for large ones > 5

\begin{document}
\section{Actual situation}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis egestas consequat eros non blandit. Proin in leo augue. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut lacinia risus vel augue laoreet, quis tristique lacus commodo. Curabitur semper maximus accumsan. Pellentesque id elit nisl. Quisque imperdiet lacus ut massa efficitur viverra. Aliquam non augue at nibh vehicula venenatis. Sed egestas metus aliquam, placerat ipsum sit amet, ornare nisi. Quisque lacus justo, placerat vitae lacus et, ultrices volutpat metus. Maecenas imperdiet hendrerit erat. Phasellus tempus rhoncus diam eget vehicula. Fusce auctor eros non sagittis accumsan. Pellentesque metus elit, consequat venenatis tellus ac, dignissim maximus nisl. Sed maximus condimentum purus at aliquam.

Aliquam ex sem, iaculis vel iaculis eget, faucibus hendrerit sem. Cras mattis eleifend nisi, vel venenatis enim finibus in. Suspendisse iaculis velit ac velit vestibulum pulvinar. Quisque non ipsum dictum, venenatis nisi a, porta justo. Sed tincidunt mauris vel quam mollis, eu tempus dui maximus. Nulla vel mauris a velit pulvinar mollis. Nullam condimentum turpis purus, non laoreet ante suscipit ut.

Donec finibus magna magna, at mollis dolor molestie a. Curabitur mattis luctus massa in hendrerit. Phasellus quis varius turpis, ornare hendrerit augue. Nulla quis lectus augue. Donec est est, sollicitudin tristique elit eget, lobortis pharetra orci. Integer tempus nisi ac elit efficitur vestibulum. Praesent eget augue id ipsum volutpat iaculis vitae ut mi. Nunc sit amet feugiat est, sed aliquam nunc. Nunc mauris nisl, scelerisque sed ligula in, viverra tincidunt elit. Nunc odio enim, elementum sed rutrum feugiat, varius ut enim. Quisque eleifend nunc metus, posuere ornare eros lacinia eu. Maecenas nulla nisi, commodo finibus imperdiet ac, aliquet sed ligula.

Aliquam gravida ac mi ac laoreet. Quisque ut luctus magna, et pretium quam. Aliquam in convallis metus. Phasellus sed est sed mauris consequat dictum ac ac eros. Sed nec eros pellentesque, sollicitudin magna iaculis, sollicitudin sapien. Aenean eget viverra ligula. Sed porta dui lacus, vitae gravida ipsum sagittis quis. Vestibulum tortor justo, consectetur vitae nulla et, efficitur blandit metus. Cras consectetur purus eleifend magna facilisis blandit. Maecenas pretium eros vel libero gravida viverra. Suspendisse pharetra ultrices suscipit. Praesent bibendum accumsan mauris.

Curabitur mattis risus quis accumsan fermentum. Maecenas vel tempus turpis. Ut sagittis venenatis turpis, sit amet vestibulum tellus. Fusce non posuere urna. Sed auctor dignissim neque, ut ullamcorper orci suscipit quis. Proin congue turpis at tellus mollis vulputate. Vestibulum faucibus massa commodo mi gravida, lobortis porttitor magna porttitor. Nulla et ipsum maximus, porta sapien vel, convallis lacus. Etiam dolor augue, laoreet id metus et, aliquet euismod nibh. Sed dictum vehicula congue.

Curabitur mattis risus quis accumsan fermentum. Maecenas vel tempus turpis. Ut sagittis venenatis turpis, sit amet vestibulum tellus. Fusce non posuere urna. Sed auctor dignissim neque, ut ullamcorper orci suscipit quis. Proin congue turpis at tellus mollis vulputate. \textbf{I do not want this line to split, but rather start on the new page entirely.} Nulla et ipsum maximus, porta sapien vel, convallis lacus. Etiam dolor augue, laoreet id metus et, aliquet euismod nibh. Sed dictum vehicula congue.



\newpage
\section{Preferred situation}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis egestas consequat eros non blandit. Proin in leo augue. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut lacinia risus vel augue laoreet, quis tristique lacus commodo. Curabitur semper maximus accumsan. Pellentesque id elit nisl. Quisque imperdiet lacus ut massa efficitur viverra. Aliquam non augue at nibh vehicula venenatis. Sed egestas metus aliquam, placerat ipsum sit amet, ornare nisi. Quisque lacus justo, placerat vitae lacus et, ultrices volutpat metus. Maecenas imperdiet hendrerit erat. Phasellus tempus rhoncus diam eget vehicula. Fusce auctor eros non sagittis accumsan. Pellentesque metus elit, consequat venenatis tellus ac, dignissim maximus nisl. Sed maximus condimentum purus at aliquam.

Aliquam ex sem, iaculis vel iaculis eget, faucibus hendrerit sem. Cras mattis eleifend nisi, vel venenatis enim finibus in. Suspendisse iaculis velit ac velit vestibulum pulvinar. Quisque non ipsum dictum, venenatis nisi a, porta justo. Sed tincidunt mauris vel quam mollis, eu tempus dui maximus. Nulla vel mauris a velit pulvinar mollis. Nullam condimentum turpis purus, non laoreet ante suscipit ut.

Donec finibus magna magna, at mollis dolor molestie a. Curabitur mattis luctus massa in hendrerit. Phasellus quis varius turpis, ornare hendrerit augue. Nulla quis lectus augue. Donec est est, sollicitudin tristique elit eget, lobortis pharetra orci. Integer tempus nisi ac elit efficitur vestibulum. Praesent eget augue id ipsum volutpat iaculis vitae ut mi. Nunc sit amet feugiat est, sed aliquam nunc. Nunc mauris nisl, scelerisque sed ligula in, viverra tincidunt elit. Nunc odio enim, elementum sed rutrum feugiat, varius ut enim. Quisque eleifend nunc metus, posuere ornare eros lacinia eu. Maecenas nulla nisi, commodo finibus imperdiet ac, aliquet sed ligula.

Aliquam gravida ac mi ac laoreet. Quisque ut luctus magna, et pretium quam. Aliquam in convallis metus. Phasellus sed est sed mauris consequat dictum ac ac eros. Sed nec eros pellentesque, sollicitudin magna iaculis, sollicitudin sapien. Aenean eget viverra ligula. Sed porta dui lacus, vitae gravida ipsum sagittis quis. Vestibulum tortor justo, consectetur vitae nulla et, efficitur blandit metus. Cras consectetur purus eleifend magna facilisis blandit. Maecenas pretium eros vel libero gravida viverra. Suspendisse pharetra ultrices suscipit. Praesent bibendum accumsan mauris.

Curabitur mattis risus quis accumsan fermentum. Maecenas vel tempus turpis. Ut sagittis venenatis turpis, sit amet vestibulum tellus. Fusce non posuere urna. Sed auctor dignissim neque, ut ullamcorper orci suscipit quis. Proin congue turpis at tellus mollis vulputate. Vestibulum faucibus massa commodo mi gravida, lobortis porttitor magna porttitor. Nulla et ipsum maximus, porta sapien vel, convallis lacus. Etiam dolor augue, laoreet id metus et, aliquet euismod nibh. Sed dictum vehicula congue.

Curabitur mattis risus quis accumsan fermentum. Maecenas vel tempus turpis. Ut sagittis venenatis turpis, sit amet vestibulum tellus. Fusce non posuere urna. Sed auctor dignissim neque, ut ullamcorper orci suscipit quis. Proin congue turpis at tellus mollis vulputate. \newpage \noindent \textbf{I do not want this line to split, but rather start on the new page entirely.} Nulla et ipsum maximus, porta sapien vel, convallis lacus. Etiam dolor augue, laoreet id metus et, aliquet euismod nibh. Sed dictum vehicula congue.

\newpage
\raggedbottom
\interlinepenalty=10000
\section{Not preferred situation}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis egestas consequat eros non blandit. Proin in leo augue. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut lacinia risus vel augue laoreet, quis tristique lacus commodo. Curabitur semper maximus accumsan. Pellentesque id elit nisl. Quisque imperdiet lacus ut massa efficitur viverra. Aliquam non augue at nibh vehicula venenatis. Sed egestas metus aliquam, placerat ipsum sit amet, ornare nisi. Quisque lacus justo, placerat vitae lacus et, ultrices volutpat metus. Maecenas imperdiet hendrerit erat. Phasellus tempus rhoncus diam eget vehicula. Fusce auctor eros non sagittis accumsan. Pellentesque metus elit, consequat venenatis tellus ac, dignissim maximus nisl. Sed maximus condimentum purus at aliquam.

Aliquam ex sem, iaculis vel iaculis eget, faucibus hendrerit sem. Cras mattis eleifend nisi, vel venenatis enim finibus in. Suspendisse iaculis velit ac velit vestibulum pulvinar. Quisque non ipsum dictum, venenatis nisi a, porta justo. Sed tincidunt mauris vel quam mollis, eu tempus dui maximus. Nulla vel mauris a velit pulvinar mollis. Nullam condimentum turpis purus, non laoreet ante suscipit ut.

Donec finibus magna magna, at mollis dolor molestie a. Curabitur mattis luctus massa in hendrerit. Phasellus quis varius turpis, ornare hendrerit augue. Nulla quis lectus augue. Donec est est, sollicitudin tristique elit eget, lobortis pharetra orci. Integer tempus nisi ac elit efficitur vestibulum. Praesent eget augue id ipsum volutpat iaculis vitae ut mi. Nunc sit amet feugiat est, sed aliquam nunc. Nunc mauris nisl, scelerisque sed ligula in, viverra tincidunt elit. Nunc odio enim, elementum sed rutrum feugiat, varius ut enim. Quisque eleifend nunc metus, posuere ornare eros lacinia eu. Maecenas nulla nisi, commodo finibus imperdiet ac, aliquet sed ligula.

Aliquam gravida ac mi ac laoreet. Quisque ut luctus magna, et pretium quam. Aliquam in convallis metus. Phasellus sed est sed mauris consequat dictum ac ac eros. Sed nec eros pellentesque, sollicitudin magna iaculis, sollicitudin sapien. Aenean eget viverra ligula. Sed porta dui lacus, vitae gravida ipsum sagittis quis. Vestibulum tortor justo, consectetur vitae nulla et, efficitur blandit metus. Cras consectetur purus eleifend magna facilisis blandit. Maecenas pretium eros vel libero gravida viverra. Suspendisse pharetra ultrices suscipit. Praesent bibendum accumsan mauris.

Curabitur mattis risus quis accumsan fermentum. Maecenas vel tempus turpis. Ut sagittis venenatis turpis, sit amet vestibulum tellus. Fusce non posuere urna. Sed auctor dignissim neque, ut ullamcorper orci suscipit quis. Proin congue turpis at tellus mollis vulputate. Vestibulum faucibus massa commodo mi gravida, lobortis porttitor magna porttitor. Nulla et ipsum maximus, porta sapien vel, convallis lacus. Etiam dolor augue, laoreet id metus et, aliquet euismod nibh. Sed dictum vehicula congue.

Curabitur mattis risus quis accumsan fermentum. Maecenas vel tempus turpis. Ut sagittis venenatis turpis, sit amet vestibulum tellus. Fusce non posuere urna. Sed auctor dignissim neque, ut ullamcorper orci suscipit quis. Proin congue turpis at tellus mollis vulputate. \textbf{I do not want this line to split, but rather start on the new page entirely.} Nulla et ipsum maximus, porta sapien vel, convallis lacus. Etiam dolor augue, laoreet id metus et, aliquet euismod nibh. Sed dictum vehicula congue.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please move the code over here. Links rot over time and then your example will not me useful to others

Comment: Thanks for modifying the example. TeX line breaking happens before page breaking is considered so there is no way to change the line breaking based on where the page break happens. It may be possible using some complicated multi-pass routine saving information in the aux file but this is likely to be highly unstable as any page break affects all later ones.  I would simply do `.\clearpage\noindent`   or `.\pagebreak\\ ` at the end of sentences where you want to force a page break.

Comment: It is possible to split a paragraph using `{\parfillskip=0pt\par}\noindent` although it occasionally looks bad. (I call this `\nopar`.)